# Checking that all foreach values meet criteria

Tags: php

I'm attempting to check an array provided from the `$_FILE` syntax. My script is allowing me to check individual objects within the array when they are stated.

**EG:**

```
$_FILES['upload1']['tmp_name'][0];
```

**The issue:**

Due to the fact that I am wanting to check ALL of the file fields, stating `[0]` next to this object isn't what I'm looking for, and was wondering how I could check that all of the `tmp_name`'s are set to the dimensions of 1920 x 1080.

**Note:**

The code below works perfectly fine, however it only checks singular objects. I would like to be able to check everything, EG: [0], [1], [2], [3] etc etc.

How would I go about doing this with a foreach loop? - I've only briefly touched on them before and am struggling to wrap my head around it.

Thanks, Rich

```
if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload1']['tmp_name'][0])) {
        echo "<span class='error'>Please fill in all of the file fields.</span>";   
exit();
}

$info = getimagesize($_FILES['upload1']['tmp_name'][0]);
function checkSize($info){
    if (($info[0] != 1920) || ($info[1] != 1080)) 
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

if (checkSize($info)) {   
    echo "<span class='error'>All image resolutions must be 1920 x 1080.</span>";
    exit();

}
```

Comment: That's my topic, this is a different question as I'm asking about foreach loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I'm going to go ahead and answer my own question as I've been researching for hours:**

```
$countthem = 0;
foreach ($files as $file) {
$file_name = $file;
$info = getimagesize($_FILES['upload1']['tmp_name'][$countthem]);
if (($info[0] != 1920) || ($info[1] > 1080)) {
echo "<span class='error'>Image resolution must be 1920 x 1080.</span>";
exit();
}
++$countthem;
}
```

By counting applying an individual object number at the end of the `['tmp_name']` array I've been able to mirror the same number that it has within the array. This method applied within a foreach loop has allowed me to check all of the file resolutions individually.